# C query regarding strings

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I was going through a site which had the following piece of code and the question following that was, what is the expected output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char *foo = "Arista Netowrks";
    char *bar = "Arista Netowrks";
    printf("%d %d\n",foo,bar);
}
```

The answer given was Both the address would be same. As the strings are read only so they would behave as global constants in read only memory. I am adept in C but this totally took my off guard. I would be thoroughly obliged if someone could elaborate the answer mentioned above. I understand that the address will be printed and I understand that its read only memory. But how does it act as global constant if it was declared inside a function and how do both the variables point to it?

Source: GeeksforGeeks.org

Comment: Strictly speaking, this program causes undefined behaviour.  Don't use `%d` to print pointers.

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281835/how-do-c-compilers-merge-identical-string-literals