# The code below outputs 1 and 0 how ever i do not know why

Tags: c++

I understand that the code below is outputing the result of a boolean question but i do not understand why it outputs 1 and 0 instead of 1 and 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string d = "abc", e = "abc";
    char a[] = "abc", b[] = "abc";
    cout << (d == e);
    cout << (a == b);

    return 0;
}
//outputs 10
```

i also tried outputing the value stored in variables a and b and got the same value for both

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string d = "abc", e = "abc";
    char a[] = "abc", b[] = "abc";
    cout << (d == e);
    cout << (a == b);
    cout << "\n" << a << "\n";
    cout << b;

    return 0;
}
// outputs 10
//abc
//abc
```

Comment: also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814457/why-do-only-some-compilers-use-the-same-address-for-identical-string-literals

Answer (score 1):

In C, `std::string` has a special `operator==` that **actually** compares the strings. Contrary to what you might read, `std::string`s are **not** equivalent to char arrays. Char arrays are essentially treated as pointers, so `==` compares the memory addresses, which are different, so the program will output `0`.

Comment: There is no `std::string` in C.

Comment: Arrays *decay* to pointers.

Comment: `Char arrays are essentially treated as pointers` This is highly misleading.

Comment: You're talking about c++, not c

Comment: Arrays ARE just pointers to sequential data in the memory

Comment: @jjj I'd say there's a difference: https://godbolt.org/z/P1z74j Calling `foo2` in that example would not be possible with a pointer and arithmetics with that type yields a different result than with a plain pointer.

Answer (score 1):

For comparing 2 arrays of char you should use strcmp, the == operators compares the pointer addresses instead of the value itself. You can also iterate the arrays and compare element by element.