# C++ equal operator in array

Tags: c++, pointers

```
const char ca[]="test";
const char cb[]="test";

const char *pca="test"; //(*)
const char *pcb="test";

cout<<(ca==cb)<<endl; //0
cout<<(pca==pcb)<<endl; //1
```

I'm quite confused about this result.

`ca` `cb` are different objects, when dealing with `ca==cb`, it compares the address of the first elements, so `&ca[0]!=&cb[0]`.

But I don't understand the behaviour of `pca` `pcb`.

Does (*) equivalent to

```
const char temp[]="test";
const char *pca = temp;
```

?

Is `"test"` an object? and both `pca` and `pcb` points to the first element of this object?

Comment: Compilers are allowed, but not required to combine storage for equal string literals. [Why do (only) some compilers use the same address for identical string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52814457/3309790)

Answer (score 1):

```
const char ca[]="test";
const char cb[]="test";
```

This creates *new* variables called `ca` and `cb`, big enough to hold the characters and terminator from the string literal given in the initialisation (not assignment), then *copies* the contents of the literal string into each.

---

```
const char *pca="test"; //(*)
const char *pcb="test";
```

This simply sets the character pointers to point to the given string literals. An implementation is free to use the *same* memory for those literals, effectively aliasing the memory for multiple purposes. It can do this with impunity since it's undefined behaviour to attempt to modify string literals anyway.

---

Regarding your final point about the pointers being equivalent to:

```
const char temp[]="test";
const char *pca = temp;
```

That is not the case. The `pca` variable now points to memory that you are *allowed* to modify (through either `temp` or `pca`).

---

Also keep in mind this string literal aliasing can be more subtle than first thought. The code segment:

```
cout << a << "is " << "invalid\n";
cout << b << "is " << "valid\n";
```

may only end up with *two* string literals stored in memory:

```
Addr:
  0   1     2      3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   11   12
+---+---+-------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+
| i | s | <spc> | \0 | i | n | v | a | l | i | d | \n | \0 |
+---+---+-------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+
```

with:

- `is<spc>` being converted to use address 0;
- `invalid\n` being converted to use address 4; and
- `valid\n` being converted to use address 6.

And, if some *other* piece of code ever needed `id\n`, it could just use address 9.